# Cómo usar firebase cuando la app está cerrada

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy usando Firebase en android para crear notificaciones en segundo plano.

He visto que desde un gestor en la pagina firebase puedes enviar mensajes o notificaciones a todos los usuario o a uno concreo usando token.

Tengo todo configurado, pero lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se cumpla una condición en mi app se envíe la notificación cuando la tienen cerrada. Para segundo plano simplemente con un Notification.builder cumple la función pero cuando se cierra no se como hacerlo.

¿Alguna idea?¿Que debo hacer en firebase? O si no hace falta usar firebase ¿Qué debo hacer?

No dispongo de código para hacer esto. Solo me registré en firebase, añadí mi proyecto y modifique el gradle para poder utilizarlo. Ahora solo tengo notificaciones en segundo plano, sin cerrar la app. Esto lo hice sin firebase. Pero para enviarlas cuando la aplicación está cerrada creo que se debe utilizar.

Saludos. Gracias.

Comment: Podrías mostrar algo de código por favor? Hablas sobre el concepto de notificaciones, supongo te refieres a FCM, y firebase tiene esa tecnología para varias plataformas, no se sabe para cual estás tratando de usarlo. Por favor edita la pregunta agregando la plataforma y agrega código para ser más preciso. Tu pregunta incentiva a votos negativos.

Comment: Editado. Es en android. Código no tengo en relación a esto. Intento saber como hacerlo.